# Get day from date Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I got a date with format 'Y-m-d', and want to get the day from it. Like if I have 2021.01.01, I want for example Friday, or Thursday depending on what day it actually is. I already got the date stored as $date and I want the day stored as `$day`.

I've already tried this, without any error, and without anything happening:

```php
$day = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('1');
var_dump($day);
```

Comment: Can't you use `->format('l')`?

Comment: Hello @shaedrich , thanks for awnsering. As you can see in my example, I've tried already, and it does not output anything for me.

Comment: It looks like it's a 1 (one) instead of an l (lowercase L).

Comment: Please add the actual and your expected output to the question. This is normally necessary to find answers and does not need that much guesswork (with all the misinterpretations that can go with it). If you need more information about this, the help section should have more guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution for you :

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2009-10-22');
$day = date('l', $timestamp);
echo $days;
```

output:

Thursday

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ,

```
$d=unixtojd(mktime(0,0,0,6,20,2007));
var_dump(cal_from_jd($d,CAL_GREGORIAN));
```

output :

```
    array (size=9)
  'date' => string '6/20/2007' (length=9)
  'month' => int 6
  'day' => int 20
  'year' => int 2007
  'dow' => int 3
  'abbrevdayname' => string 'Wed' (length=3)
  'dayname' => string 'Wednesday' (length=9)
  'abbrevmonth' => string 'Jun' (length=3)
  'monthname' => string 'June' (length=4)
```

And for your code , you just need to add your date like this

```
$d=unixtojd(mktime(0,0,0,month,days,year));
$calendar  = cal_from_jd($d,CAL_GREGORIAN);
var_dump($calendar['dayname']);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for awnsering. The code you sent underneath (Last line you sent) only outputs a long number like 2459220. I want it to output the day, not the timestamp, if I made it more clear. If there's anything I missed, please tell me.

Comment: Sorry I corrected my answer,maybe its look like you want!?

Comment: the last var_dump will return days name depend the date you put  in

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is exactly what I need, with a little twist. Now I got a line that looks like this: $day = unixtojd(mktime(0,0,0,1,5,2021)); and it works fine, but I want to add a variable as the date. The variable has a format with Y-m-d, and it must have 3 arguments. Please help.

Comment: Could i ask you? the  return of  " var_dump($day);" on your code !? , please

Comment: The var_dump output gives me something like this int(2459378). I use echo $calendar['dayname'] instead, and it shows me only the day name.

Comment: please check my second answer this could be a best answer for you depend on you date format i've found this is better.

Comment: I leave both of answers , maybe someone else will need it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you used a 1 (one) instead of an l (lowercase L). If you change that, it works fine.

```
$day = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('l');
var_dump($day);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, you seem to be using **1** instead of **l**

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$dayName = $today->format('l');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Carbon`, `->dayName` is the obvious and more explicit way:

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->dayName
```

It also allow you to have it in any language:

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->locale('fr_FR')->dayName
```